# hoverinfo not working with hovertemplate in plotly

Tags: plotly.js

I am trying to include a plotly angular wrapper line chart with markers. I have provided a custom template to show my tooltip details `hovertemplate` and I am getting the legend name associated with the tooltip.

```
Note: Hoverinfo works well without hovertemplate
```

I have a custom hover template with the legend name next to it.
    I have given the `hoverinfo:'x+y'` despite this I am still getting the legend name associated with the tooltip

Image of Actual O/P
My [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoN9p.png

Expected o/p - custom tooltip without the legend name.

However I was not successful in getting anything related on internet. Your help would be appreciated

```
constructor(){

this.mylevel ={
       x: this.x, 
       y: this.y1, 
       xaxis:'x',
       yaxis:'y',
       type: 'scatter',
       name:'level (mm)',
       hoverinfo:'x',
       hovertemplate:'here comes my custom tooltip',
       mode: 'lines+markers',  
      };
    }

ngOnInit() {
this.graph = {
data: \[this.mylevel\],
layout:{
  title: 'my chart',
  hovermode:'closest',
  hoverlabel: { bgcolor: "#fff" },
  xaxis: {title: 'years', zeroline: false},
  yaxis: {title: 'Level(%)',zeroline: false},

 }
}

<plotly-plot \[data\]="graph.data" \[layout\]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding text property and assign your tooltip value to it in your case it is `this.x` I guess. Then in hovel info specify that you want to display text.

I created a sample code hope this will help.

```
this.mylevel ={
       x: this.x, 
       y: this.y1, 
       xaxis:'x',
       yaxis:'y',
       type: 'scatter',
       name:'level (mm)',
       text: this.x
       hoverinfo:'text',
       hovertemplate:'here comes my custom tooltip',
       mode: 'lines+markers',  
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The template supports an "extra info" box that by default shows the series name. You can remove it by adding "" to the end of the template string.

More info: https://plotly.github.io/schema-viewer/?attribute=hovertemplate